# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1012, 1)

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I understand this question has been asked over and over again but i tried every possible solution yet i cant seem to get rid of this error.

I'm trying to predict stock prices using the layers below based on a database of 27 features, 1012 samples for training and 125 for testing.
- x_train.shape: (1012, 4, 27)
- y_train.shape: (1012,)

I'm using the following code:

```
def Dynamic_Trainer(rate, activ1, activ2):
    lstm_model = Sequential()
    lstm_model.add(LSTM(26, batch_input_shape=(BATCH_SIZE, TIME_STEPS, X_train.shape[2]), dropout=0.0, recurrent_dropout=0.0,
             stateful=True, kernel_initializer='random_uniform', return_sequences=True))
    lstm_model.add(Dropout(rate))
    lstm_model.add(Dense(26, activation=activ1))
    lstm_model.add(Dropout(rate))
    lstm_model.add(Dense(1, activation=activ2))
    lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
    print('XTRAIN:', X_train.shape)
    print('YTRAIN', y_train.shape)
    # Initializing The Training
    Dynamic_Trainer.history = lstm_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=2, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                             shuffle=False, validation_data=(Reformat_Matrix(x_val, BATCH_SIZE),
                                                                             Reformat_Matrix(y_val, BATCH_SIZE)))
```

I get this error: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1012, 1)`

I don't understand what i am doing wrong since when i print the shapes of i get:
x_train: (1012, 4, 27)
y_train: (1012,)
Which is to my knowledge the right shape.

Comment: What is this prediction about ? can u give a brief explanation please

Comment: Try setting return_sequences to False in the LSTM.

Comment: Im working with timeseries to predict stock prices using the lstm above, but when i set return_sequences = False i get a different  error: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_2: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. I edited the post with some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return_sequences=True` is the culprit. With it `True` it will return tensor rank 3, maybe `(1012, TIME_STEPS, 26)`,  which you can put it to another RNN layers.

But here you want to go straight to output so change this to `False`.

From comment, it seems you have more than one `LSTM`, the last one need `return_sequences=False` to have rank 2 tensor as output, the `(1012, 1)` from error log, while others need `return_sequences=True` to return tensor as rank 3 for the next RNN layers.